# "drush sql-sync" failing with Illegal string offset 'site' backend.inc:1030

Tags: 8, drush

I'm using Drupal 8.
I have an installation on my local dev machine as well as one on my remote demo machine.
I'm attempting to use drush `sql-sync` so that I can make sure my local dev has the same data as my remote demo.

The command I'm running is:

```
drush sql-sync @remote.demo @local
```

The error is:

> #### Illegal string offset 'site' backend.inc:1030
>
> The command could not be executed successfully (returned: env: drush: No such file or directory, code: 127)
>   Error: no database record could be found for source @remote.demo

My aliases file is ~/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php.

```
<?php

$local = '/var/www/drupal/';
$aliases['local'] = [
    'root' => $local,
    'path-aliases' => [
        '%dump-dir' => "{$local}drush.dbdumps",
    ]
];

$remote = '/var/www/drupal/';
$aliases['remote'] = [
    'remote-host' => 'x.x.x.x',
    'remote-user' => 'myUsername'
];

$aliases['remote.demo'] = [
    'parent' => '@remote',
    'root' => $remote,
    'path-aliases' => [
        '%dump-dir' => "{$remote}drush.dbdumps"
    ]
];

?>
```

I know it's being picked up because it shows up in `drush status`.

This is a snippet of backend.inc (the file referred to in the error):

```
1028        if ($proc['output']) {
1029            $values = drush_backend_parse_output($proc['output'], $proc['backend-options'], $proc['outputted']);
1030            $values['site'] = $site;
1031            if (is_array($values)) {
```

It seems to me that `drush_backend_parse_output()` is parsing something incorrectly but I'm unable to figure this one out. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I ran the drush command with the verbose flag:

```
drush -v sql-sync @remote.demo @local
```

The output is long but the relevant output is:

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no myUsername@x.x.x.x 'env COLUMNS=112 drush --backend=2 --verbose --root=/var/www/drupal/  sql-conf   --all 2>&1' 2>&1                       [notice]
Illegal string offset 'site' backend.inc:1030
```

It seems like the drush command run on the remote machine is generating output that my local drupal is tripping on. Not sure how to resolve this though.

**Note**: `drush --version` gives me `Drush Version : 8.0-dev` on both machines.

Comment: Are you sure that your remote drush is (more or less) the same  as your local one? I've seen errors similar to this that were caused by using an older drush version on the remote site.

Comment: I'm positive. `drush --version` gives me `Drush Version   :  8.0-dev` on both machines.

Comment: thanks @Berdir, that solved my issue. Here's a page with info on installing aa different version of Drush: http://www.drush.org/en/master/install/

Comment: That's the same page I referred to for my installation but I don't believe that's my issue is related to the version.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, despite I made sure that both sites (local and remote) are using same drush version (8.0.2)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and fixed it by specifying the `%drush-script` path for my remote machine alias. Just ssh into your remote machine and run "drush status" to find the correct "Drush script" path and put it in under `path-aliases` array. So it would look like this:

```
'path-aliases' => array(
  '%drush-script' => '/{your_path}/drush.php',
)
```